# How to use different blogger post ID in Javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, blogger

I am trying to make every article views having comma separated every 3 digit number. I have found the code for that.

But I have problem to find specific blogger post ID to use for the code to work fine.

Here's the whole code that I am trying to work on.

```
<--Viewable area /-->

<span class='entry-time'><b:if cond='data:allBylineItems.author and data:allBylineItems.timestamp.label'><span class='on'><data:allBylineItems.timestamp.label/></span></b:if><time class='published' expr:datetime='data:post.date.iso8601'><data:post.date/></time></span><span class='postviews1' style='margin-left:5px; display:display;'><a expr:name='data:post.id'/> <i class='far fa-eye'/> <span id='bacani'><span id='postviews'/></span> Views</span>
```

```
<--comma separated every 3 digit /-->

<script>var angka = document.getElementById('bacani').textContent;var reverse = angka.toString().split('').reverse().join(''),ribuan = reverse.match(/\d{1,3}/g);ribuan = ribuan.join(',').split('').reverse().join('');document.getElementById('bacani').innerHTML= ribuan;</script>
```

```
<--code for views count /-->

<script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js' type='text/javascript'/> <script> $.each($("a[name]"), function(i, e) { var elem = $(e).parent().find("#postviews"); var blogStats = new Firebase("https://sh-v-3da10-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/&quot; + $(e).attr("name")); blogStats.once("value", function(snapshot) { var data = snapshot.val(); var isnew = false; if(data == null) { data= {}; data.value = 0; data.url = window.location.href; data.id = $(e).attr("name"); isnew = true; } elem.text(data.value); data.value++; if(window.location.pathname!="/") { if(isnew) blogStats.set(data); else blogStats.child("value").set(data.value); } }); });</script>
```

I want to change:

```
<span id='bacani'><span id='postviews'/></span>
```

and

```
document.getElementById('bacani').textContent;
```

to have a specific value id which is post id from blogger. The only thing that i found from internet is

```
<data:post.id>
```

Is there any other way that i can make it work other than what I am thinking right now? I think I need specific new id to make it work for every article to have comma separated every 3 digit.

I try to use the code but it only work for one time only. I believe to make it work as a whole I need to use different code to read specific unique id base on data:.post.id from blogger post id itself. But i do not sure how to make it work. I am expecting when I know how to use different method which is making new code that find unique id for different article it would work fine.

Comment: The question is not very clear to me

Comment: I want to link script which uses to separate every 3 digit with comma into span id="bacani" .

Comment: the span id"bacani" have different value of digit from different unique id. I believe from searching internet that the formula of scripted for comma separated value only for 1 time use only. How can i make sure the scripted formula can be use to every different unique id of 'bacani'

Comment: here's the website for your reference, I would like to have views count article to have comma separated every 3 digit number to every article views count.  https://www.nakbebel.my

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just replace `elem.text(data.value)` to

```js
// original count
var count = data.value;

// count separated by comma
var separatedCount = count.toString()
        .split('').reverse().join('')
        .match(/\d{1,3}/g).join(',')
        .split('').reverse().join('');

elem.text(separatedCount);
```

The full code would be

```xml
<!-- code for views count -->
<script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script>
/*<![CDATA[*/
$.each($("a[name]"), function (i, e) {
  var elem = $(e).parent().find("#postviews");
  var blogStats = new Firebase("https://sh-v-3da10-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/" + $(e).attr("name"));
  blogStats.once("value", function (snapshot) {
    var data = snapshot.val();
    var isnew = false;
    if (data == null) {
      data = {};
      data.value = 0;
      data.url = window.location.href;
      data.id = $(e).attr("name");
      isnew = true;
    }

    // original count
    var count = data.value;

    // count separated by comma
    var separatedCount = count.toString()
      .split('').reverse().join('')
      .match(/\d{1,3}/g).join(',')
      .split('').reverse().join('');

    elem.text(separatedCount);

    data.value++;
    if (window.location.pathname !== "/") {
      if (isnew) blogStats.set(data); else blogStats.child("value").set(data.value);
    }
  });
});
/*]]>*/
</script>
```